# Check ACL role permissions for tree node

Tags: c#, kentico

I need to check if a role has ACL permission to create, modify, edit etc. on a tree node.

For instance if I have a role called "Article Editors", and a node tree starting with /articles, I need to be able to check if Article Editors have Create, Edit, Delete etc. permissions, and whether that permission is allow or deny.

Answer (score 0):

Just from top of my head you can you for example method like:

```
DocumentSecurityHelper.IsAuthorizedPerDocument()
```

Based on different overloads, but in core you can send in tree node, for which permission you are checking against and of course user.

If you want just a listing of ACLs than use

```
AclItemInfoProvider.GetAclItems()
```

Comment: There are 3 overloads of `DocumentSecurityHelper.IsAuthorizedPerDocument()` but every one of them requires a `UserInfo` object to be passed, but I have a `RoleInfo` object.